# Overlay a shp file to a FacetGrid xarray object

Tags: overlay, shapefile, facet-wrap

I am trying to add a shapefile layout to the subplots of an xarray facet plot. Right now, it is plotting it in two separate figures but I would like the layout to appear on each of the 13 sub-plots.

This is the code I have used:

```
pft = xarray.open_dataset("/home/clara/rahu_data/netcdf/jules_frac_9pft_2015_ESA_rahu.nc")
pft['frac'].loc[13,:,:]
pft = pft['frac']

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
pft.plot(x="lon", y="lat", col="type", col_wrap=5)
shpfile.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="none")
```

[Shapefile plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYhjn.png)

[pft plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMDny.png)

I am trying to add a shapefile layout to the subplots of an xarray facet plot. Right now, it is plotting it in two separate figures but I would like the layout to appear on each of the 13 sub-plots.

This is the code I have used:

```
pft = xarray.open_dataset("/home/clara/rahu_data/netcdf/jules_frac_9pft_2015_ESA_rahu.nc")
pft['frac'].loc[13,:,:]
pft = pft['frac']

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
pft.plot(x="lon", y="lat", col="type", col_wrap=5)
shpfile.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="none")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it after reading a shapefile in the cartopy world.
You can try something like:

```
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs
    from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
    from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature

    shape_feature=ShapelyFeature(Reader('shapefile.shp').geometries(),ccrs.PlateCarree(),edgecolor='black',facecolor='none')

    a=pft.plot(x="lon", y="lat", col="type", col_wrap=5, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),subplot_kws={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})

    [ax.add_feature(shape_feature,zorder=1) for ax in a.axs.flatten()]
```